# Rejection regions nested or not?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

When varying the significance level, the rejection regions can be chosen to be nested or not nested. I was wondering what some theoretical and practical considerations are in using either nested or non-nested rejection regions?  Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4):

It is not quite true that the rejection regions can be "chosen" to be nested or not. For simple hypotheses, and a continuous test statistic, the rejections regions of maximal power tests are surely nested via the Neyman-Pearson Lemma. The same goes for composite hypotheses and UMP tests.

GLR tests do not guarantee maximal power, but I do not know any practitioner that would not reject starting with the upper values of the GLR statistic. Since most common parametric tests are ultimately GLR tests, there is not much room for choice left.

Also note that you can grow an $\alpha$ level rejection region around any observed outcome. For this reason, I believe it will be very hard to justify non-nested regions.